# Is it customary JS to write getters for simple properties?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

Is this code idomatic, or should I just acess the properties directly?

```
self.isAlive = function() {
  return self.alive;
}
```

Comment: Well, it's definitively not customary to use the `this` value inside function declarations. (That's because it refers to the global object unless the function is invoked via `call` or `apply`, or bound via `bind`.) You usually use `this` inside methods and constructors, not declarations.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - changed to `self`. That was actually my original code, I just wanted to make it clearer ... nm then :)

Comment: Hm, I don't get this. If `isAlive` is a method of the `this` object, why do you return a property of the `self` object from it. If `this` and `self` refer to the same object (which is what I assume), you should stick to one name (preferably the one you created via a variable, `self` in this case) and not use both names interchangeably.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - fixed again. In my particular code snippet, this == self.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on implementation.

If you feel the property is always going to be the value, accessing the property is adequate. If you feel like there's going to be some logic that determines returning a "properly formatted" value, I would use a method (or if the value could possibly be dynamic based on other factors, a method is a good idea).

To go a step further, other languages like C# have properties making it safe to expose values, but not necessarily alter them. JS doesn't have such a method of protecting it, so often `get<Var>` is used to expose the property, but in a read-only fashion.

It's all about how *you* would like the data, while also trying to anticipate what the worst-case scenario could be if you expose the property directly vs. through a method.

Comment: That's not entirely true that js doesn't have property accessors. So if you don't need to target IE, you probably shouldn't be writing getters and setters. http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are speaking of properties in the classical OOP sense, i.e., properties of classes. In the current version of Javascript, simulating this behavior is not completely clean. Consider the following example:

```
    var Widget = function() {
        var private = 'private';
    }
```

'Widget' is a constructor function, and 'private' will be instantiated in the scope of just the constructor function. That means there is only one way to get access to 'private' from outside the constructor function scope:

```
    var Widget = function() {
        var private = 'private';
        this.getPrivate = function() {
            return private;
        }
    }
```

This will hide the private variable for each instance of Widget, but unfortunately, 'getPrivate' must now be added to each instance of Widget. You can see this occurring in the constructor function by the statement `this.getPrivate = ...`. Every time you make an instance of Widget using `var widget1 = new Widget()`, that specific instance will have a new function, 'getPrivate', added to it.

The normal way to make reusable components in Javascript is to use its implementation of Prototypical Inheritance. You assign a prototype object to the constructor function that will have shared methods and properties across all instances of the component. I will provide an example below to explain, but there are caveats to prototypical inheritance that you should become aware of if you are doing object-oriented javascript. A great [resource](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194141).

Here's an example of how this might come in to play for your example:

```
    var Widget = function() {
        this.alive = true;
    }
    Widget.prototype.isAlive = function() {
        return this.alive;
    }
    var widget1 = new Widget();
    widget1.isAlive();  // returns true
```

The problem here is that the property `alive` is being added to the object, and thus, it is publicly available, i.e., any user of your Widget can simply look through the DOM in their favorite variation of FireBug and see (as well as freely modify) this property.

Consider a variation where you attempt to hide `alive` to external users. Because `alive` is a property of `Widget` instances, you would want to include the code to hide it in the constructor, as shown below:

```
    var Widget = function() {
        var alive = true;
    }
```

However, as stated at the beginning of this post, `alive` in this case is only exposed to the constructor function's scope; therefore, it would not be accessible to methods on the prototype. The reason for this is that each of those methods do not have the same scope as the constructor function, since Javascript only has function scope.

In conclusion, if you're trying to hide data in a reusable component, javascript does not provide a clean way to do it. If you don't mind having new memory allocated on each component instance for the same methods, then you can use my second code example in this post. However, if you prefer to have your methods allocated in memory only once, then you will need to expose properties on the object instance, e.g., `this.alive = true`.

Answer (score 1):

That's subjective. Use of getters and setters is very discussed. Some people (like me) say you should always use getters and setters to follow the encapsulation principle, while others say that you shouldn't since your application would become unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1):

This is good practice if you don't want outside js code to modify your property. If this is the desired effect you might consider assigning that property using var instead of making it a property of that object. That way your code within the object can modify it but it can only be accessed through your getter

```
var alive = false;
function isAlive(){ return alive;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
function isAlive(){
    return arguments.callee.alive;
}
isAlive.alive=true;
```

This appears to be ok still in strict mode.

Another way to accomplish this is

```
function isAlive(){
    return isAlive.alive;
}
isAlive.alive=true;
```

But the problem is that someone can use the name as a string, or rename the function etc... and you can loose the status.

Comment: I explicitly mean in strict mode.

Comment: sorry... 
Your example don't have document.write... so I got no error.

Comment: @ThadeudePaula That update throws: "*Uncaught TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them*"